# Was Gunda planned as a Trash movie?

Tags: analysis, reception, gunda

There is a lot to read and talk about the 1998 Bollywood movie [Gunda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gunda_%28film%29).
General perception is that **it's so bad it's good**.

The movie holds a rating of 8.2 on IMDB and holds a cult status.

I want to know whether it was really planned this way or is it a case like [Troll 2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Troll_2)?

I remember watching [Best Worst Movie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Best_Worst_Movie), where the director was actually surprised that his movie was so poorly received.

So in this context what's the deal with Gunda?

Comment: I thought people watched it for the silliness in the movie and laughed at the scenes and dialogues. It was not meant to be funny but its just ridiculous how characters are portrayed and people found it amusing. Here is a hilarious analysis of the movie https://youtu.be/L2bFsQWaDTg done by Kanan and Biswa, maybe you have already seen it.

Comment: Yeah I have already seen it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think their priority was the quality of the film. Their priority was probably to earn money.

That being said, there are a lot of movies from that period which are like Gunda. Maybe not that bad, but pretty close. The creators of Gunda probably got lucky for it to gain cult status.

Gunda's director, Kanti Shah has made **46 movies**. Just reading their names makes me sure nothing good about Gunda was intentional. It's not like these 46 movies are really old, his latest film was in 2015.

BTW, you should really thank me. Because of you, Kanti Shah is in my search history.

Answer (score 1):

Probably not. Gunda was made like just another movie in that period. It just didn't turn out to be good!

If I am not wrong *(I might be)*, the popularity and later a cult following happened probably because of a funny review done by Indian comedians Biswa and Kanan. I personally was little aware of such movie before I watched the hilarious review; and so was the case for the people around me.

The comedians also say in their review to rate this movie with good reviews on its [IMDB](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0497915/) page.

Talking about the character portrayal, well, the director might have genuinely created such characters and story line. There isn't any scarcity of such movies in history.

Comment: It was much before Biswa & Kalyan. I found this movie via a blog by Arnab Ray (@greatbong) which was very popular too

Comment: That's why I wrote *I might be* :D
I and most of the people around me came to know about this movie, at a greater extent, via the Biswa & Kanan video.
Nonetheless, in both scenarios, the movie became popular by a third person, not associated with the movie.